# window.open pass email body variable

Tags: javascript, window.open

I am using javascript window.open to send users to a browser-based email app, like gmail (it's not gmail). I would like to pass specific form variables to the users email account, when they select the button in the form. I would like the script to open a new message window, and pop variables like the message body and subject line into the new message window. Is that possible? This is what I have tried:

```
 window.open("https://gmail.com", "_blank" + emailAddress +
              '?subject=My Learning Journal&body=' + contents);
```

Comment: You mean `window.open("https://gmail.com" + emailAddress + '?subject=My Learning Journal&body=' + contents, "_blank" );` right?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, I could put "_blank" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this using `mailto` URI, this would prompt the user to select their mail client and then pop the contents just the way you want.

```
<a href={"mailto:" + emailAddress + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + contens}>Send</a>
```

Note: Using anchor tag here is just for giving an example, you can use it similarly in other approaches like `onClick` function on a button.

Comment: Okay, if a default client is already there (as on my testing computer), then there is no way to make a choice of email client. This won't work like I need it to, but thank you!

Comment: There might be workaround possible, if you could share the email client you want to use

Comment: I want to test with gmail.com

Comment: Well you mentioned you don't want use Gmail in your question, but you can use the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides)